# Why my image isn't found?

Tags: java, image, jframe

I'm trying to make a simple JFrame with a simple image... And because it's simple, it don't work ^^
Look at the left of tis screenshot, the image exist and is in the res/textures/ folder.
[image]
Do you know why it don't find me my image ?
I think it don"t find the image because this is the result of my code :
[image]
And this is my main code :

```
    this.jframe = new JFrame();
    this.jframe.setSize(800, 200);
    this.jframe.setUndecorated(true);
    this.jframe.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0f));
    this.jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.jframe.setContentPane(new LoaderJFrame());
    this.jframe.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: In the first screenshot, the titre.png image

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: Sorry, the question is : Why the image don't appear ?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Post it in the question.

Comment: `./` means "current directory". Shouldn't you be using `../` ?

Comment: Does `new File("whatever").exists()` return true?

Comment: Look at the left of myscreen shot (that's why i show you screenshot and not only the code) i show you the image exist in "res/textures/titre.png"

Comment: Yes. But where is LoaderJFrame.java located? Unless it is in the root your path is wrong

Comment: That's not what I asked: *Does `new File("whatever").exists()` return true?*. You might have a file which exists on your local filesystem with some path, it does not mean that it is visible to your program.

Comment: @SexyTurnip the package declaration is visible.

Comment: Sorry, it's true i don't show you where are java files. my Main.java and my LoaderJFrame.java are in the same package at the same level.

Comment: I have no idea how Java works - worth a guess!

Comment: @AndyTurner, it don't return anything ... He don't read it ? When i'm testing if the image exist in my main, it say me true. But my SOP in my LoaderJFrame class don't appear. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Working ! I just had to change this line in my LoaderJFrame class :

```
public void LoaderJFrame(Graphics g)
```

by

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

Thanks for all :D

Comment: Thing is I never saw `public void LoaderJFrame(Graphics g)` in your source code given. Give us all of the code or else we can't help you.

Comment: Look at the first image. All of the code of the LoaderJFrame class is present.

Comment: You should always paste the code as text; I can hardly even read the image. But I see what you mean.